# Is it possible to trace back 403 error during ajax request in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make an ajax call with DRF and each time receive:

```
[20/Oct/2017 13:35:24] "OPTIONS /test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 82
```

I can't understand the reason of this error(I disable csrf by decorators and by middleware). Is it possible to raise exception instead of 403 response in Django to find out which middleware and which code line return 403 error?

Comment: Why is the HTTP method OPTIONS? Are you doing cross-domain AJAX?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about HTTP method OPTIONS. May you give me a link to docs? I do a cross-domain request in debug purpose(writing code in frontend and backend sides simultaneous). I lunch my DRF-backend, then lunch my frontend in IDE(NetBeans) and then see results.

Comment: Can you share with view?

Comment: Presumably, the error could caused by incorrect setting of Auth. You should to check settings, views, `authentication.py` and `permissions.py` if they are existed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

403 is **forbidden**. It may be happened because of the permission class you used. If you are using function based view(**FBV**) add decorator and set permission to **AllowAny**, if its class based view(**CBV**) use permission class to **AllowAny** . for examole

**FBV**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response

# ...

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def test_view(request, format=None):
    # ...
    # you code  
    # ...
    return Response(content)
```

**CBV**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response

# ...

class TestView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # ...
        # you code  
        # ...
    return Response(content)
```